# Span Styles not Taking Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some content being added to a page via an AJAX call, and all of my styles are working, except one:

```
.bld-txt {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

The call itself looks like this:

```
$('#quick-search').submit(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  $('.quick-search-info').empty();
  var artistName = $(this).serialize();
  $.post('/', artistName, function(data) {
    var parsedInfo = $.parseJSON(data);
    var tourDetails = '';
    $.each(parsedInfo, function(i, val) {
      tourDetails += '<li class="tour-date">';
      tourDetails += '<ul class="show-details">';
      tourDetails += '<li class="show-date"><span class="bld-txt">Date: </span>' + parsedInfo[i].formatted_datetime + '</li>';
      tourDetails += '<li class="show-venue"><span class="bld-txt">Venue: </span>' + parsedInfo[i].venue.name + '</li>';
      tourDetails += '<li class="show-location"><span class="bld-txt">Location: </span>' + parsedInfo[i].venue.city + ", " + parsedInfo[i].venue.region + '</li>';
      tourDetails += '<li class="show-tickets"><span class="bld-txt">Tickets: </span>' + parsedInfo[i].ticket_status + '</li>';
      tourDetails += '</ul>';
      tourDetails += '</li>';
    });
    $('.quick-search-info').append(tourDetails);
  });
});
```

All other classes that have styles assigned to them thus far are working, but for some reason "bld-txt" will not take effect.

I'm using a reset (normalize.css), but there's nothing in it that should be causing this.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try adding !important, does it work then? If it does you need to increase the specificity of your class style on the element. Your code has open ended `li` tags as well. Fix the structure.

Comment: @magreenberg !important didn't help. What do you mean by "open-ended?" It looks like all of them are opened and closed correctly.

Comment: @Trix I don't have anything live but I just pushed it up to github if you want to take a look. https://github.com/danemery/snapTour

Comment: I think you should edit your question and provide enough code to let others reproduce the final result. As per current code snippet and descriptions, this is impossible to be reproduced.

Comment: @Trix Based on the state of the project at the moment, I don't think I can provide a coherent batch of code for reproduction. I'll keep trying to solve it and follow-up if I do.

Comment: Stackoverflow has no magician. Always keep in mind to read your question as another user and try to be sure, if she/he can reproduce the results, as this is probably the only way you may get help here.